# Как сделать голосовое общение 2-х человек через сервер, общатся будут двое

Tags: android, flash, php

Ребята помогите решить проблему

Меня очень задолбали операторы своими говеными тарифами, надоело дарить им смартфоны в виде денег

У меня есть свой сервер пока виртуальный vds

Как можно реализовать через него голосовое общение

Чтобы было типа скайпа, но свое

т.е. общаться будут двое

Пусть это даже будет в виде флеша

Мне не понятно как передавать голос и в какую сторону копать для создания приложения под андроид

Для начала что устанавливается на сервере для передачи голоса или на чем пишется подобное?
Возможно ли такое запустить на виртуальном сервере?
Есть ли аналоги не флеша, чтоб только голос транслировать?

Знаю несколько языков, вы мне просто напишите кто знает что да как, чтоб было понятно

Comment: Решение проблемы:  пользуйся скайпом.(  Нет желания тебе на что-либо отвечать, т.к из вопроса уже все становится ясно с тобой:)  )

Answer (score 2):

Поставьте `asterisk` и `sip` телефоны.

Answer (score 2):

Поставь на пример timespeak на VDS c вебмордой.

Comment: что за программа timespeak? :)

Answer (score 2):

Написать такую штуку стоит уйму денег. Причем, понятие уйма растянется на миллионы (не рублей конечно).

Есть туча стартапов, которые уже не один год создают подобные штуки: например [Tango](http://www.tango.me/), [Viber](http://www.viber.com/) и проч. ребята. Насколько я знаю эти стартапы так и не вышли пока что на операционную прибыль.

В общем самому это поднять нереально - нужны инвесторы, нужны бабки, нужна команда.

С технической точки зрения - вопрос выглядит примерно так:

1. Нужен сервер, через который будет общаться народ
2. Нужен клиент на базе Android'а, а еще лучше подтянуть и iOS и WP8 и десктоп заодно
3. Конкретная реализация голосового обмена это [SIP API](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/sip.html)

Comment: Я конечно не инвестор, но на фоне скайпа я бы не стал вкладываться в аналог. Это не по теме.

Comment: Я о чем и талдычу...

Answer (score 0):

В свое время тоже начинал копать в эту тему.., но быстро понял, что одному программисту трудно такое реализовать. Как выше писали, нужна команда и инвестиции в проведение работ и аппаратуру...

К примеру если трафик весь будет проходить через твой сервак - то дешевый, медленный сервак быстро нагнется... Выход из этой ситуации - делать соединение напрямую клиентов, т.е. донастраивание параметров через твой сервак, а флеш, к примеру, напрямую создает подключение к другому клиенту (Если общаются только 2 то это подходит).